# Unter Megatrends versteht die Forschung solche Entwicklungen, eine ganze Gesellschaft neu zu gestalten

Tags: sentence-structure

What is the meaning of the preposition "unter" in the context of this sentence?

Comment: https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/unter+etwas+verstehen

Comment: so "unter" belongs to the verb verstehen, thanks.

Comment: @RoyPJ Correct, but I'd like to stress that "unter" does NOT correspond to "by"/"as". Instead: "to understand X by Y" ~> "Y unter X verstehen". So there is no literal translation for this type of "unter" in English.

Comment: but can we omit 'unter" in this sentence? can we say "Megatrends versteht die Forschung ...."?

Comment: no ... "unter Megatrends versteht..." => a desription of how "Megatrends" is understood ... VS... "Megatrends versteht" => sounds more like "Megatrends" (now in the position of the one who is understanding something) is understanding "die Forschung", but the sentence now has a gramatical problem since now you'd expect the word "als" followed by how it is understood ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb `verstehen` in combination with the prepositional extension (Präpositionalergänzung) `unter` means the same as the English `mean by`.

Example:

> Ich forsche im Bereich Megatrends.
>
> Was verstehen Sie unter "Megatrends"?

---

> I am researching mega trends.
>
> What do you mean by "mega trends"?